# div height problem

Tags: css

I have header, Mastercontianer and footer for my site.

I have 2 containers inside master container A(left) + B(right)

As the B container fills up , 'A' container doesn't move.

Is there any way to fill up A container with some color?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Write some code please. Depends on lots of things (tags, css used...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's many ways to achieve this using CSS.

The simplest solution is to use something called "Faux columns". This basically means that your maincontainer has a background image which is the full width and 1 pixel high. The background image is then repeated on the y-axis meaning that your columns appear to stretch consistently as the height of the main container is pushed by your A & B divs.

Here's a simple tutorial which covers this approach:

[Faux columns tutorials](http://line25.com/articles/create-sidebars-of-equal-height-with-faux-columns)